How to move the risktable legend text and title to the left in the plot with ggcuminc or survfit
I would like to to have the risktable title and risktable text to be possitioned and aligned to the very left as shown in the first picture.
Aim of cum inc plot
I have created an object:
library(survfit)
library(tidycmprsk)

fit.mh.male <- cuminc(Surv(time, status) ~ Exposure, data =  timesplit.mh.m)


fit.mh.male %>%
  ggcuminc()+
  add_risktable(
    risktable_stats = `n.risk`,
    stats_label = list(n.risk = "No. at Risk"), 
    size = 3)+
  add_confidence_interval()+
  scale_ggsurvfit()+
  labs(title = "FTMH male",
       x = "Time since surgery")+
  theme(axis.test.y = element_text(hjust = 1))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 10), 
                  ylim = c(0, 0.04)) + 
  scale_color_jama()+
  scale_fill_jama()+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 1))

In the code that I have, the risktable text is is alligned to the right - and it covers some of the numbers at risk at time = 0 and the risktable title is alligned over the number at time = 0, instead of being alligned over the risk table text.
My output of the code

@ddsjoberg maybe you know how to solve this?

To understand the problem better, it is vital to realise that the print method for a ggcuminc object creates two ggplot objects: the main panel at the top with the curves, and a little text-only ggplot at the bottom that acts as the risk table. The label "No. at Risk" is the title of the bottom plot, and the labels "Cataract" and "Victrectomy" are the y axis labels.
Using this information, we can pass the arguments to move these elements as a theme object passed to the theme argument of add_risktable:
fit.mh.male %>%
  ggcuminc() +
  add_risktable(
    risktable_stats = "n.risk",
    stats_label = list(n.risk = "    No. at Risk"), 
    size = 3,
    theme = list(theme_risktable_default(),
                 theme(plot.title.position = "plot",
                       axis.text.y.left = element_text(hjust = 0,
                            margin = margin(0, 20, 0, 0))))
    ) +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  scale_ggsurvfit() +
  labs(title = "FTMH male",
       x = "Time since surgery")+
  theme(axis.test.y = element_text(hjust = 1)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 10), 
                  ylim = c(0, 0.04)) + 
  scale_color_jama() +
  scale_fill_jama() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 1))



Data used
Note that we don't have your dataset, so I had to create one with similar characteristics and the same variable names. Here is the data I used for the above plot:
set.seed(1)

timesplit.mh.m <- data.frame(Exposure = sample(c("Cataract", "Virectomy"), 
                                               300000, TRUE, prob = c(20, 0.1)))

timesplit.mh.m$status <- rbinom(300000, size = 1, 
    prob = ifelse(timesplit.mh.m$Exposure == "Cataract", 0.008, 0.02))

timesplit.mh.m$time <- runif(300000, 0, 120)/10

timesplit.mh.m$status <- factor(timesplit.mh.m$status)

fit.mh.male <- cuminc(Surv(time, status) ~ Exposure, data =  timesplit.mh.m)


Thanks a lot @Allancameron! This works great!

I realize that due to the large numbers at risk (I have 300 000), that there are still some numbers in the risk table that disappears at time = 0. Is there any way to fix that the numbers in the risktable are brought to front, especially for the first numbers?

@Biromnie You could simply make your plotting window larger as I have done. Note that I also ensured there were 300,000 in the sample I created, and I do not have this problem because I increased the size of my plotting window appropriately.

Hey Allan! Thanks for the fast reply. Yes, I noticed that, thats great! My issue is that I have in total 6 plots (nrow = 3, ncol = 2) that I will merge together in patchwork, so the plots will be relatively small. Its for a medical journal, so im limited with the space. Any suggestions what to do? I have also tried to make the text/numbers smaller, but then I gets really difficult to see ;)
